# How do I View the HTML Source of an email in Outlook 2016

Tags: outlook, outlook-2016

I would like to view the html source code of an email in outlook 2016. It seems to have changed from the previous versions of outlook.

I am running Outlook 2016 Thank you :)

Comment: @Ctc I mean if someone sent me an html email to my Outlook, is it possible to view the source code of that html email?

Comment: You can see the source code if you convert it to .eml if the message is .msg format

Answer (score 68, accepted):

AFAIK this hasn't changed in Outlook 2016: right-click the message body and choose "View Source".

Comment: Also, if you click in certain places in the email (I think tables) the 'View Source' option isn't in the context menu for some reason...

Comment: Ya that is what I was finding as well.

Comment: My whole email is a responsive table, but I was able to get to "View Source" by zooming way out and right clicking below the footer.

Comment: View Source only shows the body of the message as HTML. This is rarely the entire message source.

Comment: Since so many emails are made of tables and images, there are not many places you actually can click sometimes to get it ... Many times have  to scroll way down to the bottom and find a small spot I can click that has it in the context menu ... which is annoying.  But, it's still there.

Comment: This answer is wrong but unfortunately this question is closed so I'll have to add a comment instead: what you want to do is right click the message in the list. This way you are always guaranteed to have the "view source" option.

Comment: How is the answer wrong? Try it. Your comment is wrong - there is no "View Source" option in the context menu that appears when you right-click an email in the folder

Comment: Ditto this doesn't work for me. This answer [from SuperUser](https://superuser.com/a/390808/39645) does work: In the "message" tab, look in the "move" section and select "Actions" -> "Other actions" -> "View Source"

Comment: I don't seem to have this option in Outlook 2016. For an inconvenient workaround: File tab -> Options -> Trust Center, and then Trust Center Settings -> Email Security. Under Read as Plain Text, check the "Read all standard mail in plain text" check box. https://support.office.com/en-us/article/read-email-messages-in-plain-text-16dfe54a-fadc-4261-b2ce-19ad072ed7e3

Comment: The answer by @just Nik is how I was able to do this on Outlook for Mac. Right clicking the email in the list view shows the View Source option.

Comment: This does **not** work for meetings however. At least in Office 365.

Comment: The body in Appointments is Rich Text (RTF), so no HTML - but Meeting Invitations have HTML in the body.