# How can I make an email interactive/actionable (perhaps via Javascript) by a little icon click without having to goto another website?

Tags: javascript, email, outlook, gmail, webmail

I read this thread:
[Is JavaScript supported in an email message?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3054315/is-javascript-supported-in-an-email-message)

But still the question remain relevant to me.

So how does really Yammer messages are actionable in Outlook?

There are thumbs up that's possible, there're sometimes voting that's possible.
And from my memory (rather bad on this one) I think Gmail too allow that to a certain extent.

Are there any libraries that can be embedded in the Email HTML construction that support this kind of feature?

--
Edit

An example screenshot is as follows. Sorry about the black boxes as I had to remove all private info from there). As you can see the Thumbs up is a link works indeed, without having to visit Yammer. All inside Outlook. (Note the Red arrows marked are there for the "Like" functionality and the "Others voted" functionality)

The state change that I invoked is notable in the Email message as well as Yammer post in the same exact way.

[image]

Comment: The thumbs up are images wrapped in a link. When you click the link it opens a URL and does something. Nothing is actually happening inside the mail client. Mail clients DO NOT execute JavaScript.

Comment: The links don't really open up anything. I've added an image to the post above now. As you can see the Outlook email just stays there. But when you click the thumbs up, it changes the colour from white (or transparent hand) to a yellow hand.

Comment: Please paste in the question the html of that email (you can remove the sensitive data) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38058596/how-do-i-view-the-html-source-of-an-email-in-outlook-2016

Comment: Quite tricky to get the HTML on that email in Outlook. When I try to forward the text become static. So perhaps a plugin within outlook or outlook itself support this active/interactive functionality.

Answer (score 1):

Outlook won't run Javascript or submit HTML forms from email messages for security reasons.

Your best bet is [Actionable messages in Outlook](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook/actionable-messages/)

Answer (score 1):

Any scripts are not supported by email client applications for security reasons. As Dmitry noted, Outlook doesn't run any JavaScript or HTML forms in message bodies.

Email applications vendors introduce their own solutions for injecting interactive elements into message bodies, in case of Office 365 that is https://adaptivecards.io/. Adaptive Cards are an open card exchange format enabling developers to exchange UI content in a common and consistent way, see [Adaptive Cards Overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/adaptive-cards/) for more information.

Comment: That makes much sense. I still haven't gotten a way to check the source of the Email message in my Outlook. But while looking through found out I not just thumbs up, but also can reply to the Yammer post inside my Outlook. Great insight on the AdaptiveCards! Thanks!